parbox/minipage width bigger than it should be
The following code produces a parbox in my report. I have also tried it using the minipage environment, but I end up getting the same issue.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, top=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{4cm}
    
    \noindent \hspace*{8cm}
    \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth - 8cm\relax}{
        \justifying
        \noindent \lipsum[5]
    }}
\end{document}


I am not sure what is causing the small offset the box has. I thought it was the \justifying environment, but apparently it is not. By making a framed box I could verify the issue is somewhere else.
Does anyone know what might be causing the small offset?
Thanks in advance.

Instead of specifying your \hspace to move the \parbox to the right margin I'd simply use \noindent\hfill. To set the width you can then use any width, but if you want to make sure that the width to the left of the \parbox is exactly 8cm use \linewidth-8cm, and if you wrap an \fbox around it you also have to compensate for its padding and rule width, so the total width of the \parbox contents becomes \linewidth-8cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule.
Also a \parbox is always by default justified, and the \parindent is set to 0pt inside it, so you don't need \justifying or \noindent inside of it.
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=3cm, top=3cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{4cm}

\noindent\hfill
\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-8cm-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{%
    \lipsum[5]
}}%

\noindent\rule{8cm}{1pt} % showing that the indentation is indeed precise
\end{document}



Thank you! That did the job!

If you want that the left edge of the \parbox is exactly 8cm fron the left margin
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  left=3cm,
  top=3cm,
  right=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  showframe,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxright}{m+b}
 {%
  \par\raggedleft
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimeval{\columnwidth-#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}{#2}}%
  \par
 }{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-8]

\begin{boxright}{8cm}
\lipsum[5]
\end{boxright}

\lipsum[2][1-6]

\end{document}

Defining a suitable environment is better, because it allows uniformity across the document and, even if you use it once, you don't write complicated code in the document environment, making maintenance easier.

For instance, you might want to experiment with some white space before and after the box.
\NewDocumentEnvironment{boxright}{m+b}
 {%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}\raggedleft
  \fbox{\parbox{\dimeval{\columnwidth-#1-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}}{#2}}%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
 }{}



\noindent \hspace*{8cm}SPACE
    \fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth - 8cm\relax}{
        \justifying% this does nothing
        \noindent \lipsum[5]
    }}

in addition to \textwidth you have an inter word space., also \fbox adds 2\fboxsep from the 2 rules either side, and 2\fboxsep from the padding either side.
If the \fbox is just for debugging, that space will go once you remove it, and a % after \hspace*{8cm} will prevent the inter-word space.
For safety I'd add one after the { but as that is in vertical mode the space there is ignored.
Justification is the default, and there are essentially no cases where \justifying should be used, if it has an effect it is usually a sign of a mis-placed \raggedright elsewhere that has leaked out of its intended scope.
